# How can I digitally merge two sides of stereo into mono sound?

Tags: audio

I'm deaf in one ear, which means I can't use earbuds as I can only hear one side. I've tried an adaptor that mixes both analogue signals electrically, but the sound quality is noticibly reduced.

What I'd really like for the software inside the phone to digitally mix both sides before it becomes an analogue signal. Is there a setting or a downloadable add-on to do this?

(I use the built-in music player and 'Google Listen' podcast player on a Samsung Galaxy S2.)

Comment: I don't know about apps to do this system-wide, but a music player (poweramp) has this feature IIRC.

Comment: [Voodoo Sound](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.projectvoodoo.controlappdonate) can do this for the original SGS, but doesn't look like it supports the S2.  Just to note, if you want to do it for all audio then any solution will need root; single apps are different as Richard notes.

Comment: If you root/flash your phone, I believe DSP Manager (included in most Cyanogen ROMs and probably some others) can do this.

Answer (score -1):

I would think that one of the one-ear bluetooth headsets would do this automatically.

Comment: Generally those will only support Bluetooth 1.x audio and not A2DP, meaning that they'll be at a ridiculously low bitrate that isn't suitable for music.

Comment: I just bought myself a bluetooth headset and now I find I can only route phone calls through it. Oh well.